# Sogo Connector Addon not working

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I just downloaded the sogo connector from http://www.sogo.nu/downloads/frontends.html to sync owncloud contacts with Thunderbird 24.6.0.

According to the documentation this should enable the option "remote adressbook" in the "New" menu. But this wasn't the case for me. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Markus

Answer (score 1):

did you look for the "remote adressbook" in the normal Thunderbird menu or did you change into the adressbook first? Because that's actually what you should do. Go into the adressbook and open "file" "new" "remote adressbook". There it should be.

Good luck,
Gabriele